# how to return certain data from an array by keys

Tags: php, arrays

I was looking for a way of solving a problem of returning keys and data from an a array.

The keys are 7,8,9,10 and "size","atime","mtime","ctime" from an array returned by the stat() function.

```
function returnDataByKeys($keys,$array){

    $tmp = array();
    foreach($keys as $keyValue)
        $tmp[$keyValue] = $array[$keyValue];

    return $tmp;
}
```

As for my question, I am looking for a more array_* function way of extracting the desired keys & values as a block with the keys preserved.

With all the other `array_*` functions I have seen, I don't see one that allows you to put in key data and return only those keys if found in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* I'm understanding your question correctly, it's as simple as this:

```
array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(array('size', 'atime', ..)))
```

http://php.net/array_intersect_key

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nicely done, I was confused as to why array_flip was used, so I experimented, still not sure why it works like it does.

Thanks.

Comment: `array_flip` saves you from having to type `array('foo' => null, ..)`. The values you want to filter by need to be keys.

Comment: It is a shame there is no built-in for this among all other less useful functions.

Comment: @Сухой27 I think this is trivial enough to not require yet another function... Yes, it'd be nice to have, but it's not a big deal breaker IMO.

Comment: @deceze I'm also worried about mental health of the person who will read my code. Such examples of code are great candidates for `WTF` category.