# Decode full array and encode part of it

Tags: php, json, decode

Let's say I have the following JSON string:

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
```

How would I only display the property 'Name' in an updated JSON string? For example, I would want the code to be transformed into this in an updated variable `$json2`:

```
$json2 = '[{"Name":" Jim"},{"Name":" Bob"}]';
```

I have attempted to do this using the code below but receive the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Name on line 9

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$decode = json_decode($json, 'false'); 
$json2 = json_encode($decode['Name']);

echo $json2;
```

`$json2` returns 'null'.

Comment: $decode[0]['Name']

Comment: You have *an array* of items, not just one item. You need to at least loop over the items.

Comment: @B.Kocaman That only returns the first name.

Comment: `$decode = json_decode($json,true); 
$json2 = json_encode(array_column($decode,'Name'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true); 

$transformed = array_map(function (array $item) {
    return array_intersect_key($item, array_flip(['Name']));
}, $decoded);

$json2 = json_encode($transformed);
```

The `array_intersect_key` is [the easiest method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28037575/476) to pluck specific keys from an array, and doing it in an `array_map` over a whole array is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 5.3+:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

$newArray = array_map(function ($array) {
    return ['Name' => $array['Name']];
}, $decode);

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. That returns `[" Jim"," Bob"]` while I would like `'[{"Name":" Jim"},{"Name":" Bob"}]'`

Comment: Your 'false' means true :)